# Custom FrameDecoder in netty

Tags: buffer, netty

I have problem with FrameDecoder of netty as following.

- packet is fragmented in to {n} frames then FrameDecoder processing correctly.
- If many packets are composed to one frame and send to server(when client sending small packet data continuously), then FrameDecoder only reads the first packet. The remaing is ignored.

Can i get the remaining data to be continued executed by FrameDecoder?

```
public class BinaryFrameDecoder extends FrameDecoder {
    @Override
    protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Channel channel, ChannelBuffer buffer){
        if(buffer.readableBytes() < 2){
            return null;
        }

        int length = buffer.getShort(buffer.readerIndex());
        if(buffer.readableBytes() < length + 2){
            return null;
        }
        buffer.skipBytes(2);                
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you replace:

```
return buffer;
```

with:

```
return buffer.readBytes(length);
```

because it is very likely that `buffer` contains more than one message.

Comment: Actually, yes, buffer contains more than one message. 
I have used method frame = extractFrame(buffer, buffer.readerIndex() + 2, length);
It works well! Thanks @Trustin!